# AngularJS passing object into isolated scope

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create a reusable html element / angular directive that will be used inside of ng-repeat so I want to pass it the values it will display in the DOM.

Something worth noting, I don't care for the values to bind. They can be a one-time binding simply displaying their values the first time ng-repeat creates them.

For example here is my directive:

```
 app.directive('newsListing', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: 'true',
        templateUrl: '../Pages/Views/Templates/newsListing.html',
        scope: {},
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            //Fairly sure this is where the binding needs to happen?
        }
    };
});
```

My HTML template:

```
<div>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt logo-green"></span>
<label>{{DateValue}}</label>
<label>{{Category}}</label>
<label class="noBorder">{{Content}}</label>
```

What I want the ending product to be:

```
<news-Listing Date="{{someValue}}" Category="{{someValue}}" Content="{{someValue}}"></news-Listing>
```

I have never created a directive before and all the guides I am trying to follow don't explain the scope, and the way binding happens inside of a directive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```js
var app = angular.module('anApp', []);
app.controller('aCtrl', function($scope) {


$scope.data = [{date:"2000-12-12",category:"sport",content:"this is a test"}]
});
app.directive('newsListing', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: 'true',
        template: '<div><label>{{date}}</label><p>{{category}}</p><p>{{content}}</p></div>',
        scope: {
          date:'@',
          category:'@',
          content:'@'
        },
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            
        }
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="anApp" ng-controller="aCtrl">
   <div ng-repeat="d in data">
   <news-listing date="{{d.date}}" category="{{d.category}}" content="{{d.content}}" ></news-listing>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you this makes a lot of sense now. Thank you for the in browser demo.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example of what you want: https://jsfiddle.net/jonva/kuk3pbbz/

```
.directive('newsListing', function() {
return {
  restrict: 'AE',
  replace: 'true',
  template: '<div> < span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt logo-green" > < /span> < label > {{dateValue}} < /label> < label > {{category}} < /label> < label class = "noBorder" > {{content}} < /label>',
  scope: {
            dateValue: '@',
            content: '@',
            category: '@',

  },
  link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
    //Fairly sure this is where the binding needs to happen?
  }
};
});
```